# Save the font in firebase in Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have more than one button and more than one Font
Each button gives the text a different font

The problem is to save it on Firebase
How does it come?

Sorry if it's simple, but I'm a beginner

```
@IBAction func Font1(_ sender: Any) {
    detilesTextview.font = UIFont(name: "Futura", size: 40)
}
@IBAction func Font2(_ sender: Any) {
    detilesTextview.font = UIFont(name: "VEXAITALIC", size: 40)
```

This is the save button in firebase

```
 let value = ["sub": self.subjectLB.text , "detiles" : self.detilesTextview.text , "ImgSub" : imgSub , "SubID" : udid , "Color" : self.labelColor , "Alignment" : self.data0 , "sizeFont" : self.SliderSize ] as [String : Any]
                    setRef.setValue(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

As per Firebase [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types), `Color` and `Font` are not supported data types and Firebase cannot infer based on these objects alone.

You would have to create a class/struct that conforms to `Codable` in order to store these data types. (See [Firebase Custom Objects](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data))

```
public struct Font: Codable {

    let name: String
    let size: Int

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name
        case size
    }
}
```

I hope this helps =). Happy Coding!